# What project encoding I must set in Netbean project property to open files encoded using the DOS character set (Code page 437)?

Tags: php, netbeans, encoding, netbeans-7, file-encodings

The problem is that I don't see any encoding in the drop-down list of available encodes on Netbean project property that match any of the names that [DOS character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) have. I have installed Netbean PHP, but I don't think that make any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a strict sense :
This character set was **not conceived** as a code page.

It was simply the graphical glyph repertoire available in the original IBM PC.

This character set remains the primary font in the core of any EGA and VGA-compatible graphics card.
Text shown when a PC reboots, **before any other font can be loaded from a storage medium**.

The standards ISO 8859, currently defined in 15 different 8-bit character sets for information exchange. The structure of the character set corresponding to the first 128 positions of the characters of the 7-bit ASCII character set.

ISO 8859-1 is next to US-ASCII and UTF-8, the most important and most frequently used character set. And the best choice to use it in Netbeans as a 437 replacement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, all files opened now without any warning and I can read tildes, and ñ, etc.